# Not Able to create 1 ERC 20 tokens with 18 decimals of my own using code provided from open zeppelin truffle

Tags: truffle, erc-20, openzeppelin

I am trying to create my own ERC 20 token but I ran some issue with openzepelin code.

Here is the code

```
var SampleToken = artifacts.require("SampleToken");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SampleToken, "Test token", "TES", 1*10**18);
};
```

This is the code from "2_initial_migration.js". I understand that I need to put initial supply at the third input. So I put 1*10**18 because in my understanding that would translate to 1 token because of the 18 decimals. but when I execute it I receive an error like this

[image]

and

[image]

I received an answer that because the configure file is in JS and the biggest number it can handle are 253 - 1 and that number is bigger than that. if that so, how do I use this code to at least create 1 token instead of 0.00001 token?

Comment: Turning an answer into a comment - instead of `1*10**18`, you can use either one of the following:

Comment: 1. `new web3.utils.BN(10).pow(new web3.utils.BN(18))`

Comment: 2. `web3.utils.toWei(1)`